# Adding almost duplicates together and removing old duplicate in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies for any inaccuracies in my wording, I'm fairly new to Python and brand new Pandas.

So I currently have a dataframe which contains about 1,000 accounts and their corresponding balance. However, some accounts exist twice in the data, once with their normal account number and once with "AM1" at the end of it. How can I create a new/edit the existing dataframe(either way works), so that 900002 and 900002AM1's balances are combined into 900002's balance and then 90002AM1 is removed from the df? Thank you. I know groupby would work (it's how I got to the current DF), but obviously I would need to be able to remove 'AM1' from all account numbers and then do :

```
df.groupby(['account#']).agg({'balance':'sum'}).resetindex)
```

**Current DF:**

| account# | balance |
| --- | --- |
| 900001 | 35.00 |
| 900002 | 25.00 |
| 900002AM1 | 25.00 |
| 900003 | 40.00 |
| 900004 | 20.00 |
| 900004AM1 | 10.00 |

**Desired DF:**

| account# | balance |
| --- | --- |
| 900001 | 35.00 |
| 900002 | 50.00 |
| 900003 | 40.00 |
| 900004 | 30.00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract number from `account#` column:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['account#'].str.extract(r'(^\d+)', expand=False)) \
      .sum().reset_index()

  account#  balance
0   900001     35.0
1   900002     50.0
2   900003     40.0
3   900004     30.0
```

What `str.extract` does?

```
>>> df['account#'].str.extract(r'(^\d+)', expand=False)
0    900001
1    900002
2    900002  # <- 900002AM1
3    900003
4    900004
5    900004  # <- 900004AM1
Name: account#, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Looks like the data in 'account#' is a mix of str and int (it's completely random, nothing to with whether it has text characters or not), so the int's get removed during this. Now to convert everything to a str first. Edit: just converted everything to a string and it now works. Thanks again

Comment: In your sample, the values prefix in `account#` seems to be a number so I use `^\d+` (important: `^` to match the beginning of string) to match that. If your data are not formatted like this, you have to find another pattern but the method still the same